# Widget with update timer

Tags: android, service, android-widget, android-broadcast

I need to create service in android, which will be running several times a day and update data in the widget. The update time is set depending on the previous update. I have no idea how to implement this. Can U told me some steps of what I need to do and what I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

Create service with Thread within, something like this:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
    private static UpdateThread updThread;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (updThread == null) {
            updThread = new UpdateThread();
            updThread.start();
        } else {
            updThread.wakeUp();
        }
        return START_STICKY;        
    }

    public class UpdateThread extends Thread {  

        protected void waitFor(long time_ms) {
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    if (time_ms > 0) wait(time_ms);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // pass
            }
        } 

        @Override
        public void run() {         
            while (mContinue) {
                // do your periodical code and widget update via broadcast intent here
                // time_in_ms is result of "previous update"
                waitFor(time_in_ms);
            }       
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help you.